# TCL : regexp to find if while for in a string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to write a regexp to search for for/if/while keywords in a string as read from C++ source code file but exclude any words which include them like:

```
WhatifYes()
Whatfor()
Waitforwhile()
```

I have written my regexp like below:

```
if { [ regexp {(for|while|if)(\s+)(\()} $lineValue ] } {
```

But it is not picking up cases like:

```
while(( int x = 0 ) > 0 );
while(( int x = 0 ) > 0 )
for(int y =0 ; ; )
for(int y =0 ; ; );
if( (int x = 9) > 0 )
if( (int x = 9) > 0 );
```

Initially I thought cause my regexp is framed to be like:

```
if/for/while \s+ ( #space or multiple spaces
```

But I tried including spaces in above example :

```
while (( int x = 0 ) > 0 );
while (( int x = 0 ) > 0 )
if ( (int x = 9) > 0 )
if ( (int x = 9) > 0 );
```

Still the regexp is not working - please let me know what regexp I should use to capture them?

Comment: Wouldn't if/while/for always have a space or start of line in front of them?. Seems like you should have a space/start-of-line before them in your regex. And then after them can be space or "(". Or maybe space/"("/end-of-line. But there is always if/while/for inside comments which probably cannot be handled with just one regex.

Comment: Thanks yes we need to exclude the strings if/for/while in comments also. Well there are chances that they may begin from a new line or something like this { do if(x > y) { } }

Comment: If you're really keen on excluding things in comments, you *must* use a full parser. Anything else is just getting too complex; there will be just too many interlocking rules. (What's more, if you're looking to understand C++, good luck! You'll need it…)

Comment: @Prakash, what I don't get is that [you've been shown a way to get your hands onto an *already parsed* C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13143067/720999), down to tokens.  Why did you revert to trying to brute-force the task using regexes instead of trying to implement a (very) simplified parser which would process the chain of tokens vera++ parsed out for you?  Yes, you'll need to implement a state machine and stuff, but this *is* the way to go.

Comment: @kostix, I understand your point but actually I am using an organization framework where we get code to process after tokens are already parsed. The framework provides code lines as specific type - say instead of identifier we would get statements, similarly for for loops - for etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is easy to address, and part is very hard.

The easy part is ensuring that you've got a whole word: the `\m` constraint escape only matches at the start of a word, and the `\M` constraint escape matches at the end, so we can use:

```
# Nothing capturing; you can add that as necessary
# Ellipsis for the bits I've not talked about yet
regexp {\m(?:while|if|for)\M\s*...} ...
```

The very hard part is matching the part in parentheses. The problem is that that's really a “language” (in a theoretical sense) that requires a different kind of parser than a regular expression to match (i.e., a recursive descent parser, which has a more complex state model than the finite automatons used in RE matching). What's more, using `()` characters in those expressions is common. The easiest approach is instead match against a close parenthesis that's at the end of the line, possibly followed by a semicolon, but that's definitely not properly correct. Alternatively, supporting a limited number of levels of nested parens is also possible.

```
# Match a few levels...
regexp {\m(?:while|if|for)\M\s*\((?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)} ...
```

So, let's break that RE down:

```
\m                                Word start
(?:while|if|for)                  One of the keywords 
\M                                Word end
\s*                               Optional spaces
\(                                Open paren
  (?:                             Either...
    [^()]                           Non-paren...
  |                               Or...
    \(                              Open paren
      (?:                           Either...
        [^()]                         Non-paren...
      |                             Or...
        \(                            Open paren
          [^()]*                      Non-parens
        \)                            Close paren
      )*                            ... as many of the above as needed
    \)                              Close paren
  )*                              ... as many of the above as needed
\)                                Close paren
```

If you look at the above, you'll notice a pattern. Yes, you can keep on nesting to do as deep as you want. What you *can't* do is make the RE engine do that nesting for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the descriptive details. It really help me a lot in better understanding regexp. Please note that I tried using both the regexp but unable to map it to examples of if/for/while mentioned in the question? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks I found the problem in my code - fixing it resolved the issue and worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, the above code won't handle unbalanced parentheses in comments, strings or character literals. Parsing is hard!

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you are using \s+. That means there must be at least one space/tab/line-break. Use \s* (0 or more whitespace) and add logic for what comes before:

```
if { [ regexp {(^|[ \t])(for|while|if)(\s*)(\()} $lineValue ] } {
```